# String IO to element.etree

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree, stringio

I want to parse StringIO in form of xml with etree, hovever I have following error.
Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
from io import StringIO

def main():
    in_mem_file = StringIO()
    in_mem_file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
    in_mem_file.write('<tag>')
    in_mem_file.write('</tag>')
    print(in_mem_file.getvalue())
    e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(in_mem_file).getroot()
```

This raises following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: It works if you provide the complete XML content when creating the `StringIO` object. Using `write()` does not work.

Comment: What will work? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Provide the whole XML document when creating the `StringIO` object. Using `write()` does not work (but I don't have an explanation for that).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

XML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tag>
    </tag>"""

in_mem_file = StringIO(XML)
tree = ET.parse(in_mem_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the cursor position of the StringIO object before handing it to ET:

```
in_mem_file = StringIO()
in_mem_file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
in_mem_file.write('<tag>')
in_mem_file.seek(0)
```